# Python Queue.get() freezes the execution when using multithreading.Process?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I am spawning several threads of one function and collect its output. Here is the code.

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def myfunc():
    def count_freqs(part, q):
       freqs = (do some stuff)
       q.put(freqs)


    def thread_joiner(data_parts):
       threads = []
       q = Queue()
       for part in data_parts:
           thread = Thread(target=count_freqs, args=(part, q))
           #thread = Process(target=count_freqs, args=(part, q))
           thread.start()
           threads.append(thread)

       for t in threads:
           t.join()

       return [q.get() for _ in range(len(data_parts))]

    new_freqs = thread_joiner(data_parts)
    return new_freqs
```

The code above works and I am able to collect the required output. However when I switch to spawning `Process` (uncomment the line with `Process` and comment the line with `Thread` accordingly) the `q.get` then locks the application which means that `Queue` object does not have any results to return so it infinitely waits.

1. Why is that happening?

Comment: Can you post your full code, including your call to `thread_joiner(data_parts)`  You can leave (do some stuff) -- it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Since you said you were on linux, I've removed my answer.

Comment: Hmm, you've made an edit where you made `count_freqs` a nested function. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, `count_freqs` is a nested function.

Comment: Rechecked again, I was wrong, the lock appears not in `q.get()` but in `t.join()`

Comment: Ok, then this is likely a dupe. Just move the calls to t.join after the calls to q.get. If that doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll undupe it.